# Is writing to two separate channels reliably sequential?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

If I have a select on two channels:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-chan1:
        // do something
    case <-chan2:
        // do something else
    }
}
```

And in a separate goroutine I write sequentially to those channels:

```
chan1 <- "blah"
chan2 <- true
```

Am I guaranteed to see "do something" execute before "do something else"?

I know that select chooses randomly if it has two unblocked channels, but I was thinking that writing to the first channel might reliably "interrupt" the writing goroutine if the select is already blocking, implying that the select would run on the unblocked first channel before the second write.

Comment: Individual channels are ordered. Any other ordering you must orchestrate yourself.

Comment: Presumably that select statement is in some kind of loop? Otherwise only the first case proceeds (and then the sender blocks forever on the second send).

Comment: @Peter yep it's in a loop, sorry, I elided too much from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can rely on this if the channels are unbuffered. See the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_7).